# A new topology on the dual of a locally convex space?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, duality, locally-convex-spaces

Working with the separable quotient problem for locally convex spaces we (with Saak Gabriyelyan) arrived to an interesting topology on the dual of a locally convex space and we would like to know if this topology had been considered in the literature.

It is defined as follows.

Let $X$ be a locally convex space over the field $\mathbb F$ of real or complex numbers, and $X^*$ be the linear space of all linear continuous functionals on $X$.

A subset $F\subset X^*$ is called *weakly$^*$ bounded* if for any $x\in X$ the set $\{f(x):f\in F\}$ is bounded in the field $\mathbb F$.

By $\beta^*$ we denote the family of weakly$^*$ bounded subsets of $X^*$.

A subset $B\subset X$ is called *$\beta^*$-bounded* if for any weakly$^*$ bounded subset $F\subset X^*$ the set $\{f(x):f\in F,\;x\in B\}$ is bounded in the field $\mathbb F$. The family of $\beta^*$-bounded subsets of $X$ is denoted by $\beta^*_*$.

It is easy to see that each $\beta^*$-bounded set $B$ in $X$ is bounded in the standard (von Neumann) sense: for any neighborhood $U$ of zero there exists $n\in\mathbb N$ with $B\subset nU$. So, the bornology $\beta^*_*$ is contained in the bornology $\beta$ of all bounded sets.

On the dual space $X^*$ consider the topology $\beta^*_*(X^*,X)$ of uniform convergence on $\beta^*$-bounded subsets of $X$.

It is clear that this topology contains the weak$^*$ topology $\sigma(X^*,X)$ of $X^*$ (i.e., the topology of  uniform convergence on finite subsets of $X$) and is contained in the strong topology $\beta(X^*,X)$ (of uniform convergence on bounded subsets of $X$). So,

$$\sigma(X^*,X)\subset\beta^*_*(X^*,X)\subset\beta(X^*,X).$$

If $X$ is a Banach space, then $\beta^*_*(X^*,X)=\beta(X^*,X)$ is the topology generated by the dual norm on $X^*$.

But already for normed spaces the topologies $\beta^*_*(X^*,X)$ and $\beta(X^*,X)$ can be different. For example, if $X=\ell^2_0$ is the pre-Hilbert space of all eventally zero sequences in $\ell_2$, then $\beta^*_*(X^*,X)=\sigma(X^*,X)\ne\beta(X^*,X)$.

> **Problem.** Has the topology $\beta^*_*(X^*,X)$ been considered in the literature? What about the bornology $\beta^*_*$ on $X$. Was it known?

Comment: How does it relate to the [Mackey topology](//books.google.com/books?id=bvuRuwuFBWwC&pg=PA163) $\tau(X^*,X)$ on $X^*$ (a.k.a. uniform convergence on $\sigma(X,X^*)$-compact convex subsets of $X$), which is also between $\sigma(X^*,X)$ and $\beta(X^*,X)$?

Comment: The bornology $\beta_*^*(X,X^*)$ consists of all subsets of $X$ which are bounded with respect to the topology $\beta(X,X^*)=\beta(X,(X^*,\sigma(X^*,X))$ (uniform convergence on all weak$^*$-bounded subsets of $X^*$), right? (It might be appropriate to look at more general dual pair $\langle E,F\rangle$ to make the situation more symmetric.)  The dual of $(X,\beta(X,X^*))$ can be strictly larger than $X^*$. Nevertheless, when $X^*$ is considered as a subspace of that dual, $\beta_*^*(X^*,X)$ is the relative topology of the strong topology.

Comment: Good luck with the separable quotient problem!

Comment: Saak Gabriyelyan pointed me out that the topology $\beta^*_*(X^*,X)$ can coincide with the topology $\beta^*(X^*,X)$ considered by Jarchow in his book on page 154. And the bornology $\beta^*_*$ is just the family of all bounded sets in the topology on $X$ generated by the neighborhood base at zero consisting of all barrels.

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler Surprisingly, but there is no definite inclusion relation between the topologies $\beta^*_*(X^*,X)$ and $\tau(X^*,X)$: For a barreled space $X$ we have $\tau(X^*,X)\subset \beta^*_*(X^*,X)=\beta(X^*,X)$, but for the pre-Hilbert space $X=\ell^2_0$ the inclusion is reversed: $\sigma(X^*,X)=\beta^*_*(X^*,X)\subset\tau(X^*,X)\subset\beta(X^*,X)$.